# Get variable from template in vue js method

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I configured project for working nodejs+vuejs. I had a code which render page in backend with some variables.

```
return res.render('registration.html.twig', {token: token});
```

How i can work with variable `token` from Vuejs component(methods)

```
export dafault {
  methods: {
    someMethod() {token?}
 }
}
```

Iam able to work with this variable in simple script in root template like

```
let x = {{ token }}
```

Comment: Instead of `let x = {{ token }}` use this `window.token = {{ token }}` then in your method `someMethod() { console.log(window.token) }`

Comment: @Molda it works, but it looks like really shit code. Maybe exist some other methods in vuejs?

Comment: Are you saying you have Vue render the page on the back end, but you also have Vue on the front end with a component that wants some data from the back end component?

Comment: @RoyJ I render page by nodejs backend. And i can easy get access to them form simple js script. But i cant work from vuejs component with this variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render a hidden field with the token value.
In the `created` hook, find the hidden field and get its value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    token: null
  },
  created() {
    const tokenEl = document.getElementById('token-field');

    this.token = tokenEl.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input id="token-field" type="hidden" value="the token">
  The token is {{token}}
</div>
```

Comment: Its working variant too, but i shouldnt paste this variable in html code. So variant wit window variable best which i find for now.